# Installing ruby gems permission denied issue on windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-7

Guys I'm trying to install the `gem live8` on windows7 but usually after typing the command `gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8`
I got this issue

```
C:\Sites\translation>gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - C:/Users/compumagic/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%443/latest_s
pecs.4.8
```

also I opened the command screen as administrator so how I can fixed this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

1. Install Ruby 64 bit
2. Instal DevKit 64 bit
3. Update rubygems - gem install rubygems-update

Use: `C:\RubyDevKit>gem list` for local gems

Comment: of course I installed the DevKit but still got this issue

Answer (score 1):

try with `-mingw32` option.
For example:

```
gem install pg -mingw32
```

Comment: It worked to install but then I cannot run it nor list it. Where does it go?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I disabled my antivirus and it helped!